# Get Pub/Sub message's messageId field from PubSubIO with Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible the get somehow the messageId field of a Pub/Sub message in a DoFn after using the PubSubIO Beam source to read the messages?

I need the default id which was assigned by the Pub/Sub service. I want to log it for debugging purposes.

Using a custom attribute for the unique id and the withIdAttribute() method is not possible for me, because I have no influence on the publisher in this case.

I use the 2.2.0 version of the Dataflow Java SDK.

Comment: It doesn't look like the Java SDK gives access to the `messageId` or the `publishTime` of the message. The `PubsubMessage` class only has member variables for the message payload and the message attributes. This should be requested as a new feature.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3489

Comment: Is there no way to integrate [API calls](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) and try to get [message data](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) that way? The API call returns the messageID field as well.

Comment: While reading the message, have you tried using this API ? `PubsubIO.readMessagesWithMessageId()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for [reading the Pubsub message id was added](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8370) starting with Beam v2.16.0. To turn it on, replace `.readMessages()` with `.readMessagesWithMessageId()` in your pipeline setup then it is as easy as `message.getMessageId()` after that change.

Comment: thanks - took me a while to figure it out :-) FWIW, I am even using `readMessagesWithAttributesAndMessageId` to get all the info I need

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes you can use the [seek option](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-qs).

It creates a snapshot of the messages which you can replay when needed.